# How to fix the following error in Catch block of Java code?

Tags: java, try-catch, printstacktrace

I have a code snippet which is throwing error when using `printStackTrace()` under `catch` block of my code. Following is the code snippet.

```
         try
     {
            # Debug Code added on 19 Feb 2016
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "baseDNs[i] = "+baseDNs[i]);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "search ="+search);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "attributes = "+attributes);

        it = basicCmAgent.find_managed_objects(baseDNs[i], search, attributes);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        # Debug Code added on 19 Feb 2016
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught Error : "+e.printStackTrace());

        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not find managed objects with base DN " + baseDNs[i]);
        return false;
     }
```

Following are the errors:

```
       asses/xml-apis.jar:../3pp_libraries/cxa_classes/irp3gppR99_330_j140.jar -d lib com/ericsson/nms/temip/importer/BasicCmConnection.java
    com/ericsson/nms/temip/importer/BasicCmConnection.java:177: 'void' type not allowed here
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught Error : " +e.printStackTrace());
                                     ^
Note: ./com/ericsson/nms/temip/importer/BasicCmConverter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
*** Error exit code 1

Stop.
*** Error exit code 1

Stop.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: What's up with those negative votes guys? I understand for some people this might not be a very big issue but for a beginner like me this is still a question.

Answer (score 2):

`printStackTrace()` has a void return type, so you can't concatenate it to a `String` or use it as an argument for another method.

You might want to use `getStackTrace()` instead.

```
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught Error : "+e.getStackTrace());
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.printStackTrace()` does not return a String it returns void and prints the stack trace. You are trying to do `String + void = String` which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at this line

```
 logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught Error : "+e.printStackTrace());
```

The return type of e.printStackTrace is void. You cannot concat String +void.

Better use e.getStactTrace();